# oleDbexception was unhandled by user code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I cannot see the added data in the data table when debugging starts it doesn't have any error but when I click button1 it shows me errors (unhandled by user code) unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As OleDbConnection
    Dim strInsert As String
    Dim cmdInsert As OleDbCommand
    Dim vt As Byte,  vm As Byte
    Dim sze As Byte


    con = New OleDbConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Packet Size=4096;Data Source=.;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=borjara;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Persist Security Info=False;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Workstation ID=ABDI;Use Encryption for Data=False")



    If RadioButton4.Checked = True Then vt = 0

    If RadioButton5.Checked = True Then vt = 1


    If RadioButton6.Checked = True Then vm = 0
    If RadioButton7.Checked = True Then vm = 1
    If RadioButton8.Checked = True Then vm = 2

    If RadioButton9.Checked = True Then szs = 1 
    If RadioButton10.Checked = True Then szs = 0



    con.Open()
    strInsert = "insert Into t1(jens) Values (" & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text & "')"
    cmdInsert = New OleDbCommand(strInsert, con)
    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()//error is here
    con.Close()

    con.Open()
    strInsert = "insert Into t1(bazsho) Values (" & DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text & "')"
    cmdInsert = New OleDbCommand(strInsert, con)
    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

    con.Open()
    strInsert = "insert Into t1(name and lastname,email,number,address,lenght,wideth,turi,glasstype,glass) Values (" & n & ",'" & TextBox1.Text(+" / " + TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "'," & vt & "," & vm & "," & szs & "')")
    cmdInsert = New OleDbCommand(strInsert, con)
    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    TextBox5.Text = ""
    TextBox6.Text = ""

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `"insert Into t1(jens) Values (" & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text & "')"` You don't have `('` you have `(`. Why aren't you using parameters? What if `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text` is `');DROP TABLE [Users];--`? Why don't you dispose all those `IDisposable` resources? Why aren't you using C#?

Comment: I wrote it with c# but I have the another problem this time there isn't any error when inserting in the table but the texts in the  textbox doesn't appear in the table,the code is 
       strsql="insertintot5(nameandlastname,number,email,address,length,wide) values(' " + "'"+ "," + TextBox1.Text + "'" + "," + TextBox2.Text + "'" + "," +  TextBox3.Text + "'" + "," +  TextBox4 + "'" + "," +  TextBox5 + "'" + "," +  TextBox6 + "') ";

Comment: Are you looking at the right database? If you have an `mdf` in your project it's probably getting copied to `bin/Debug/whatever.mdf` every time you build it.

Comment: Also use parameters.

Comment: I use the right database and I don't have mdf in my project other information that I select from the page it correctly shown in the table just the textboxs are problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no opening quote in the values of the first two Inserts.